# Openshift connection error

Tags: ssh, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I don't know if I'm on the right place but if not sorry in advance!

I have an app in openshift with tomcat running and since a couple days ago my app gives me "Not found" in the browser. I did restart the app in the webconsole and nothing.

So I thought that mybe the problem is in the tomcat so I tryed to check the log but I couldn't connect over ssh to the app. Then I runned again the setup to generate a new keypair but when the command rhc setup runs gives me:

```
Your private SSH key file should be set as readable only to yourself.  Please
run 'chmod 600 C:\Users\Artur\.ssh\id_rsa'

An SSH connection could not be established to
standard-projectxserver.rhcloud.com. Your SSH configuration may not be correct,
or the application may not be responding. Authentication failed for user
XXXXX@standard-projectxserver.rhcloud.com
(Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)

Checking for a domain ... projectxserver

Checking for applications ... found 1

app http://app-projectxserver.rhcloud.com/
```

I search over the net I already set the keys manualy and in the ssh console gives me error and I cannot connect:

```
"Permission denied (publickey, gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)"
```

What I'm doing wrong? Or even better, what I can do to connect?

(I cannot recreate this app because the war I use I don't have anymore, so I need this working to save everything again!)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was afterall in the openshift DNS!! they fixed that for me

Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1):

Could you change permission on private key file via change mode command(chmod 600) as it is showing in error.

> Your private SSH key file should be set as readable only to yourself. 
>   Please  **run 'chmod 600 C:\Users\Artur.ssh\id_rsa'**

otherwise you delete the existing public key from settings panel on openshift web console and create your keys with **rhc setup** command.

Comment: I try already that... but I'm on windows and I cannot run chmod command (I think)

Comment: delete the all files in .ssh directory and try rhc setup again.I think when rhc will not find the keys it will create the files and new configuration